# My deadbolt isn’t retracting any more and turning it doesn’t do anythjng

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I have a Schlage Encode and unlocking and turning the thumb turn. I was able to take it  apart but doesn’t seem like it’s catching when I turn it manually. Also a piece fell out that I’m assuming may be important. Any ideas on how to fix?

[image: Deadbolt picture]

[This video is of my freely turning the part to move the tongue](https://imgur.com/a/ekYYMnt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a broken deadbolt. As you say, it appears to be missing an important component. The Encode uses a tapered deadbolt so that it can more easily be operated by the small motor inside the lock, so I wouldn't expect it to be reliable with a standard deadbolt. You will likely need to go directly to Schlage for the part.

Comment: This part is definitely not serviceable without serious compromise in reliability. The failed mechanism is most likely something like a gear tooth that broke off, so there's just no way you can repair that to anywhere close to the original strength.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to replacing the deadbolt, not repairing it. By 'the deadbolt' I mean the assembly shown in the video, not the whole deadbolt lockset.

Comment: Yep. The bolt mechanism shown is a single replaceable part, not really worth repairing. Think about the hassle if your repair lasts just long enough to engage the lock and then refuses to retract the bolt...

Comment: I was going to buy a standard Schlage deadbolt to replace but good to know these details. 

I actually was able to call Schlage (their customer service line takes forever) and they offered to ship a new one and at the same time since I couldn’t use my door lock they said to go buy a normal deadbolt and install temporarily while I wait for the replacement. They’d the reimburse me for that purchase and apologized for the inconvenience. Top notch customer service.

Comment: Good to hear! Also it's nice to know a regular deadbolt will work, at least temporarily. I bet it's a little more finicky than the tapered one this comes with, so keep an eye on it until you get the right part back in place.

Comment: I thought I could just use the other bolt but they said it wouldn’t work since it’s different like you said (and I didnt try to just replace only the bolt). The rep said to replace the entire Encode with the standard deadbolt in the meantime.

Comment: Got it, that makes more sense.